# AVAsset preferred transform for a custom AVVideoComposition

Tags: ios, orientation, avfoundation, avasset, avvideocomposition

I have created a custom AVVideoComposition class and used it like this:

```
AVAsset *asset = ...
AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithPropertiesOfAsset:asset];
videoComposition.customVideoCompositorClass = [MyCustomCompositor class];
MyCustomInstruction *instruction = // custom instruction holding CIFilter that is applied to every video frame
videoComposition.instructions = @[instruction];
```

After export session used like this:

```
AVAssetExportSession *session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
session.outputURL = ...
session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
session.videoComposition = videoComposition;

[session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    ...
}];
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1744/_index.html) if I'm using `AVVideoComposition`, a track's `preferredTransform` won't work. Also with custom `AVVideoCompostion` instruction I can't set `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` with *setTransform:atTime:*.

How to get video with correct orientation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465746/ios-avfoundation-setting-orientation-of-video

Comment: Please, read edited end of my question. I have seen this question, but it hasn't been helpful.

Comment: Did you solve this Tom? We are stuck on the issues ah

Comment: It was a long time ago so I'm not 100% sure. I think I ended up manually correcting transformation matrix.

Comment: Any chacne you have the code you used?

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Comment: Hey Tom, we are still stuck on this issue...  I'm talking on behalf of my team. We are a small startup based in Tel Aviv, we are developing advanced video edit app that is using custom AVVideoCompositing to compose the final video. We have encountered some interesting yet challenging issues regarding CIImage and OpenGL conversations within the compositor. We taught, In case you are interested, to do some 2-3 hours consultant session (paid of course) and see maybe you can assist us or direct us to the correct direction. Would it be something you are interested in?