# Rotating Video with PBJVision and AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avasset, pbjvision

I'm currently developing an iOS app using [PBJVision](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) and am trying to save landscape videos in the correct orientation.

I use the writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum: completionBlock: method to save the photo to the device:

```
[self.library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum: videoPathURL
                                 completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {

    [self encodeVideoOrientation:assetURL]; // method below

    if (error.code == 0) {

          [self.library assetForURL:assetURL 
             resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
             // assign the video to the album
             }
             failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                 NSLog(@"Failed to save video to library");
           }];
     } else {
     }
}];
```

and then I use the saved video's assetURL in a method I wrote called *encodeVideoOrientation* with the intention of overwriting the file with the rotated video.  Note that I apply the same rotation (90 degrees) to all videos for testing - yet no transformation is applied to the video, regardless of the orientation.

```
- (void)encodeVideoOrientation:(NSURL *)anOutputFileURL
{
    CGAffineTransform rotationTransform;
    CGAffineTransform transformToApply = videoAsset.preferredTransform;
    CGSize renderSize;
    CGFloat newWidth;
    CGFloat newHeight;
    float currentVideoRotation;

    AVURLAsset * videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:anOutputFileURL options:nil];
    AVAssetTrack *sourceVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

    CGSize size = [sourceVideoTrack naturalSize];

    // below, I test rotating the video regardless of orientation to check if portrait videos become rotated, which they do not

    if (self.currentOrientationByAccelerometer == LANDSCAPE_RIGHT){
       currentVideoRotation = M_PI; // for testing, video should appear upside down
       newWidth = size.height;
       newHeight = size.width;
       NSLog(@"Should be landscape right");
    } else if (self.currentOrientationByAccelerometer == LANDSCAPE_LEFT){
       currentVideoRotation = M_PI; //for testing, should appear upside down
       newWidth = size.height;
       newHeight = size.width;
       NSLog(@"Should be landscape left");
    } else { //default to portrait
       currentVideoRotation = M_PI; 
       newWidth = size.width;
       newHeight = size.height;
       NSLog(@"Should be portrait");
    }

    renderSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);
    rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(currentVideoRotation);    

    AVMutableComposition* composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
     [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
     [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:rotationTransform]; //Rotations here?

     AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
     [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

     AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
     AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTrack];
     [layerInstruction setTransform:transformToApply atTime:kCMTimeZero]; //Rotations here?
     instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: layerInstruction];

     AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
     videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,30);
     videoComposition.renderScale = 1.0;
     videoComposition.renderSize = renderSize;
     instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);
     videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

     AVAssetExportSession * assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition                                                                    presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];

     NSString* videoName = @"export.mov";
     NSString *anOutputFileURLPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];

     NSURL * exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:anOutputFileURLPath];

     if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]  fileExistsAtPath:anOutputFileURLPath])
     {
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:anOutputFileURLPath error:nil];
      }

      assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
      assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
      assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
      assetExport.videoComposition = videoComposition;

      [assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ^(void ) {
         switch (assetExport.status)
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
             //                export complete
             NSLog(@"Export Complete");
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             NSLog(@"Export Failed");
             NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
             //                export error (see exportSession.error)
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
             NSLog(@"Export Cancelled");
             NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
             //                export cancelled
             break;
     }
 }];

}
```

The export completes successfully, but no transformation seems to be applied to the video regardless of the CGAffineTransform.

I referenced this SO post in writing my code:

[iOS AVFoundation: Setting Orientation of Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465746/ios-avfoundation-setting-orientation-of-video)

And this appears to be an open issue according to this post on the project's github:

https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision/issues/84

**How do I save a rotated a video captured using PBJVision?**