# Detect Video playing full screen in Portrait or landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, video

I engaged into this more than two days. I couldn't get any solution please.

I have requirement is video should play Portrait inline , full screen , landscape. My problem here is how to identify the video is playing full-screen landscape or Portrait. I have implemented `viewWillTransitionToSize` method. But `AVPlayer` has full-screen arrow button. How I can identify user clicked that option.

The second requirement , once video complete, create view on top of video show replay or next or previous option.

This is my code;

```
 if videoCellVal == nil {
            videoCellVal = videoCell

            comPlayerControl = AVPlayerViewController()

            if let player = comPlayerControl {

                let videoURL: String = "http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/11/sp/11/playManifest/entryId/"+selectedSubmission.transcodeRefId+"/format/applehttp/protocol/http/a.m3u8"
                let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: videoURL)! )
                commmentPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                player.player = commmentPlayer
                player.view.frame = videoCell.frame
                player.view.sizeToFit()
                player.showsPlaybackControls = true
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerDidFinishPlaying:",
                    name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)


                videoCell.addSubview(player.view)
            }

        }

      func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Video Finished")
    let DynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100))
    DynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
    DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius=25
    DynamicView.layer.borderWidth=2
    DynamicView.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)
    self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to know in which mode video is playing (portrait in fullscreen or landscape fullscreen)?

Comment: I have 3 scenarios . Inline video (fixed high & below other UI) , full-screen portrait or landscape. Here portrait or landscape only i need to  show next , previous video button.

Answer (score 7):

For the detecting the Full screen or video size change you can use KVO for the AVPlayerViewController, code can be like this:

```
[comPlayerControl .addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"videoBounds" , options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)]

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
           print("KeyPath \(keyPath)")
        if keyPath == "videoBounds" {
            print("New Video Bounds \(change)")
        }
    }
```

In the `change` dictionary you can check the change in the video frame/bounds change

For the rotation as you mentioned you may have to use `viewWillTransitionToSize` or `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification or you can check the current orientation using `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` as i didn't find any method which can check the change in the ongoing video

Still if you need to detect video orientation you may check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25833399/4557505 , and other answer in that link

For the repeat of the video you can set the time to zero like this in your code:

```
func playerDidFinishPlaying(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let item = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
            item.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
            //you may directly play the video or can do further processing
        }
    }
```

to play item in the queue at the end of the item you may try with `commmentQueuePlayer.advanceToNextItem()`

You may try putting replay,next,previous button in the `contentOverlayView`

```
let topView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, comPlayerControl.view.bounds.width,44))
        topView.backgroundColor = UIColor ( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.379 )
        let btnNext = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,80,44))
        btnNext.setTitle("Next", forState:.Normal)
        btnNext.addTarget(self, action:"playNext", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
        btnNext.userInteractionEnabled = true
        btnNext.enabled = true
        topView.addSubview(btnNext)
        comPlayerControl.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(topView)
```

---

**Update**

For the `observeValueForKeyPath` you may try something like this

```
var avWidth:CGFloat = 0
var avHeight:CGFloat = 0

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "videoBounds" {
        let rect = change!["new"]! as! NSValue

        if let newrect = rect.CGRectValue() as CGRect? {
            if newrect.width > 0 || newrect.height > 0 {
                if avWidth > 0 || avHeight > 0 {
                    if newrect.width > avWidth || newrect.height > avHeight {
                        print("Full Screen")
                    } else if newrect.width < avWidth || newrect.height < avHeight {
                        print("Normal screen")
                    } else {

                    }
                }
                avWidth = newrect.width
                avHeight = newrect.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. When I click Next button , it didn't trigger button. `func playNext(){
        print("===playNext")
    }`

Comment: in the first code block there is code of `observeValueForKeyPath ` function , or do you want the full code to check the bound size ?

Comment: @HardikDG can we use KVO to know when full screen button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the `AVPlayerItem` of the `AVPlayer`then it has a `videoComposition` setting which has a `renderSize` -- you could examine the `renderSize` `width` and `height` to determine if you are in landscape or portrait.

Comment: you can use the `currentItem` property to get at the item in the `AVPlayer`

Comment: `videoComposition` is only applicable for "File Based Playback", it is not supported for streaming over `http`, which means it will clearly not work in OP's case.