# AVPlayerViewController full screen button Action?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have added AVPlayerViewController view half of my current viewcontroller view then playing video from URL so far everything okay and it is working as excepted.

Actually i wanted to do landscape mode when user clicks on full screen button and here not able to find out that button action. i have tried many things nothing helps

[Detect Video playing full screen in Portrait or landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323259/detect-video-playing-full-screen-in-portrait-or-landscape)

Is there any **notification**  or **presentedViewController** or something else to find out?

I have already read so many question and did not get any answers so that posting here.

```
if self.player == nil {
            self.playerVwController.view.bounds = self.videoPlayerView.bounds
            self.playerVwController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.videoPlayerView.frame.size.width, height:self.videoPlayerView.frame.size.height)
            self.videoPlayerView.addSubview(self.playerVwController.view)
        }

 @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerView: UIView!
    var player : AVPlayer!
    let playerVwController = AVPlayerViewController()
```

Comment: are you used the backbutton or only you want to rotate  the AVPlayerViewController

Comment: AVPlayerVeiwcontroller need to show full screen

Comment: are you used the backbutton or only used fullscreen button

Comment: only full screen button there is no custom button

Comment: then why you make struggle just rotate your AVPlayerViewController or your videoPlayerView

Comment: full screen button available in avplayercontroller, i want to get that action first, then  rotate AVPlayerViewController your videoPlayerView

Comment: oh , canyou show that cide of this

Comment: i dont understand what u are asking?

Answer (score 2):

Proper way to find a action use KVO to video player `contentOverlayView` bounds..

as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323259/detect-video-playing-full-screen-in-portrait-or-landscape)

Anyway The KVO will not work for iOS 11(i am not sure about this, but we have faced), So you would subclass your

**AVPlayerViewController** as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645800/force-orientation-not-working-in-ios-10-devices/46662306#46662306)

Comment: Actually it works. But you should use `frame` instead of `bounds` key.

Comment: @NickKibish Did using bounds lead you to trouble or works as expected?

Comment: @NickKibish here working with out any problem and it is in live